# pushing the back arrow randomly puts cursor into overwrite mode in all apps in windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard

I have a 2 week old computer, and no weird "running in the background" apps installed. I've been having this issue since I got it, where randomly when pushing the back arrow to edit, the cursor gets put in overwrite mode, and I have to push the insert key to turn it off. I've been using windows 10 on several computers for years and have never seen this issue. is it perhaps a defective keyboard? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Press **<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>** This will open onscreen keyboard, here you can test.if here no problem means check your keyboard and clean it/Replace it